# How can I convert VC++'s DATE Type To C#'s DateTime?

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, date

I got a binary file, and one of record field stored some date infomation.

The save program is written by VC++ and using the DATE type.

How can read it into C#'s DateTime type ?

---

BTW: I tried DateTime.FromBinary, but it looks wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Try [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Vinay's answer, the VC++ DATE is really a double.  Just read in a double and then convert based on the description.

Here is some sample code for the conversion:

```
double CDate = 8.50; //The DATE from C++
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);  //Start at 12/30/1899
int days = (int)Math.Floor(CDate); //Get the days (integer part)
double hours = (CDate-days) * 24; //Get the hours (fraction part)

newDate = newDate.AddDays(days).AddHours(hours);
```

**EDIT**
Or use DateTime.FromOADate as suggested by Joe.

*The beauty of SO, you get to learn new things.*

Answer (score 0):

If it's an OLE DATE, use the information available from [here](http://www.quickmacros.com/help/COM/IDP_OLE_DATE.html):

> The DATE type is implemented using an
>   8-byte floating-point number. Days are
>   represented by whole number increments
>   starting with 30 December 1899,
>   midnight as time zero. Time values are
>   expressed as fractional part. Time
>   precision is 1 second. This type is
>   also used to represent date-only (the
>   fractional part is 0) or time-only
>   (the whole number part is 0) values.

Using this, you can convert to a CLR DateTime.